# Floating images left

Tags: html, css

i'm a little rusty on html and css and i cant get 2 images to float, one on top of the other. heres the code...

```
    <div class="kbody">
        <img class="kimg1" src="img1.jpg" alt=" " width="375px" height="auto">      
    <div id="ktxt">
        <p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        Kristallnacht occurred on November 9-10, 1938. Also known as the night of 
        broken glass, it was an organized attack on the Jews. Hitler had Nazis all over 
        Germany and Austria that burned synagogues, broke store windows, stole from the
        stores, killed a couple dozen Jews, and arrested twenty thousand more. A few days 
        later Germany made an &quotatonement fine&quot that added up to over one billion dollars 
        and placed it on the remaining Jews. </p>
    </div>
    <img class="kimg2" src="img3.jpg" alt=" " width="375px" height="auto">
    </div>
```

and the css...

```
.kbody {
width:800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
/*border-style:solid;
border-width:3px;*/
}

.kimg1 {
padding-left:5px;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
float:left;
}

.kimg2 {
padding-left:5px;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
float:left;
margin-top:10px;
}

#ktxt {
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:10px;
/*border-width:2px;
border-style: solid;*/
width:350px;
height:330px;
margin-left:402px;
font-style:arial, sans-serif;
color: #336699;
font-size:14pt;
}
```

what am i doing wrong??
heres what it looks like with this code
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fbFE.jpg

Comment: `float` doesn't put stuff on top of each other...

Comment: i ment i want the botton pic directly underneath the top one

Comment: oh, sorry. I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 1):

To move the second image under the first:

```
.kimg2 {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="kbody">
    <img class="kimg1" src="img1.jpg" alt=" " width="375px" height="auto">      
<div id="ktxt">
    <p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    Kristallnacht occurred on November 9-10, 1938. Also known as the night of 
    broken glass, it was an organized attack on the Jews. Hitler had Nazis all over 
    Germany and Austria that burned synagogues, broke store windows, stole from the
    stores, killed a couple dozen Jews, and arrested twenty thousand more. A few days 
    later Germany made an &quotatonement fine&quot that added up to over one billion dollars 
    and placed it on the remaining Jews. </p>
</div>
<img class="kimg2" src="img3.jpg" alt=" " width="375px" height="auto">
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put a clearfix between the elements you want to show them in separate lines. I would write a global css rule like `.clearfix { clear: both; }` and put a div before the second image;
2. Instead of writing bunch of `&nbsp;` use CSS `text-indent` property;

Sample Code:

```
<div class="kbody">
    <img class="kimg1" src="img1.jpg" alt=" " width="375px" height="auto">      
    <div id="ktxt">
        <p>
        Kristallnacht occurred on November 9-10, 1938. Also known as the night of 
        broken glass, it was an organized attack on the Jews. Hitler had Nazis all over 
        Germany and Austria that burned synagogues, broke store windows, stole from the
        stores, killed a couple dozen Jews, and arrested twenty thousand more. A few days 
        later Germany made an &quotatonement fine&quot that added up to over one billion dollars 
        and placed it on the remaining Jews. 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <img class="kimg2" src="img3.jpg" alt=" " width="375px" height="auto">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap your image

html

```
<div class="kbody">
        <div class="imageWrapper">
        <img class="kimg1" src="img1.jpg" alt=" " width="375px" height="auto" />
        <img class="kimg2" src="img3.jpg" alt=" " width="375px" height="auto" />
        </div>
    <div id="ktxt">
        <p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        Kristallnacht occurred on November 9-10, 1938. Also known as the night of 
        broken glass, it was an organized attack on the Jews. Hitler had Nazis all over 
        Germany and Austria that burned synagogues, broke store windows, stole from the
        stores, killed a couple dozen Jews, and arrested twenty thousand more. A few days 
        later Germany made an &quotatonement fine&quot that added up to over one billion dollars 
        and placed it on the remaining Jews. </p>
    </div>

    </div>
```

css

```
.imageWrapper {
    float:left;
    width:375px;
}
```

hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

easier way is `<img src="yourimage.jpg" align="left" />`

Answer (score 0):

As you want your picture to be floated to left side is not possible as you do. So, you should define your html alternatively for what you want as..

```
<div class="kbody">
    <div class="kimg">
         <img ..image1../>
         <img ..image2../>
    </div>
    <div id="ktext">your text...</div>
</div>
```

Now define the css.

hints:

```
.kimg{width: 300px;}
#ktext{width: 300px;}
```